# .NET MAUI binding two DataType on single XAML tag

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I have the following XAML code:

```xml
<ContentPage x:DataType="viewmodel:MonkeyViewModel">
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MonkeyList}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Monkey">
                <Label Text="{Binding Id}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Label Text="Edit">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            Command="{Binding EditCommand}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

The `MonkeyList` and `EditCommand` come from `viewmodel:MonkeyViewModel`.

The `Id` and `Name` come from `model:Monkey`.

On the tag `<TapGestureRecognizer>` , the `{Binding EditCommand}` doesn't work due to the `EditCommand` not being found in the data context of `Monkey`.

How can I make the `EditCommand` binding on `MonkeyViewModel` and `Id` binding on `Monkey`?

I would expect the `<Label>` works like a html `<A>` link: `<a href="javascript:edit(id)">Edit</a>` or: `<a onclick="edit(id)">Edit</a>`

Comment: use a [Relative binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the Command binding to use a [Relative Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings#bind-to-an-ancestor) as follows:

```xml
<TapGestureRecognizer 
    Command="{Binding EditCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:MonkeyViewModel}}}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
```